# Wierd Initialization in Template Parameters

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <bool B, typename T = void> struct enable_if {using type = T;};
template <typename T> struct enable_if<false,T> {};

template<bool B, class T = void>
using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<B,T>::type;

template<
        typename T, 
        enable_if_t<is_integral<T>::value,bool> = true
        >
struct MyTypeWhichIsdependentOnIntegralTypes{};
```

The above code in C++ uses an enable_if, just wanted to know this weird syntax while using it `enable_if_t<is_integral<T>::value,bool> = true` why is `= true` necessary when I remove it and try to use the created type it gives error.

Comment: What error do you get? please post a [mcve] with the compiler error.

Comment: any reason you do not use [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)? (while using `is_integral`)

Comment: It's not a test. It's `bool = true` for the template parameter. You'll often see `int = 0` or `void* = nullptr` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Thats one application of [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) (substitution failure is not an error). When the condition in `enable_if` is `true`, you get

```
template<
        typename T, 
        bool = true
        >
struct MyTypeWhichIsdependentOnIntegralTypes{};
```

`bool = true` is an unnamed template argument with default value `true`. It serves little purpose when the condition is `true`. It is only there to fail when the condition is `false`:

```
template<
        typename T, 
        "not a type" = true   // <- enable_if<false,T> has no type member alias
        >
struct MyTypeWhichIsdependentOnIntegralTypes{};
```

The default argument is used so it isnt necessary to specify the argument:

```
MyTypeWhichIsdependentOnIntegralTypes<int> foo;
                                 //     ^^ no need to specify 2nd argument 
                                 //        because it has a default
```

Comment: `template <bool B, typename T = void> struct enable_if {using type = T;};` doesn't `T = void` used for default type initialization.

Comment: @9he0nix Yes, for `enable_if` (not your template), so you often see `enable_if_t<is_integral_v<T>>* = nullptr` - which becomes `void* = nullptr`

Comment: @9he0nix what? Thats a completely different tempalte argument now. The `T` in `enable_if` is whatever you choose it to be. You cannot provide a default argument for `void` hence `bool` is used. `enable_if` can be used also differently for SFINAE. Here you can find an example where `void` is used: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if

Comment: @9he0nix the default `void` for `T` is the argument to `enable_if`. The `true` is the default argument for the unnamed `bool` argument where `bool` results from `std::enable_if_t<true,bool>`